# Can I create a Cloud Page using the REST/SOAP API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I would like to create a cloud page (landing page) using Postman or some other external source. Basically I would like to create the page, and also define the HTML content of the page and get the link of that page through the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API available for Cloud Pages, so you are left with only manual content creation.